# Two filters (RANGE) in different fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am a beginner in elasticsarch and I wanted this query below to work with the two filters, having two range of different fields, but only the first range is working.

This filter is working normally:

"range" : {"pgrk" : { "gte" : 1, "lte" : 10} }

Could someone tell me why this second filter below doesn't work?

"should" : {
            "range" : {"url_length" : { "lte" : 100 } }

--------------------------Follow my query below with the two filters--------------------------

```
 {

    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,

    "sort" : [
            { "pgrk" : {"order" : "desc"} },

             { "url_length" : {"order" : "asc"} }
        ],

        "query": {

    "bool": {
    "must": {

    "multi_match" : {
    "query": "netflix",

    "type": "cross_fields",
    "fields": [ "titulo", "descricao", "url" ],
    "operator": "and"
            }
         },
         "filter": {
         "range" : {"pgrk" : { "gte" : 1, "lte" : 10}    }
          },


    "should" : {
            "range" : {"url_length" : { "lte" : 100 } }
            }

            }
    }


          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, what is your requirement as index mapping and sample documents are not provided but I created my own mapping and sample documents **to show you how to create multiple range queries in filter context.**

Please comment, so that I can modify if its results are not according to your requirements.

### Index Def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "url": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "pgrk": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "url_length": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
    "title": "netflix",
    "url" : "www.netflix.com", --> this shouldn't match as `pgrk > 10`
    "pgrk": 12,
    "url_length" : 50
}

{
    "title": "Netflix",  --> this should match both filetrs
    "url" : "www.netflix.com",
    "pgrk": 8,
    "url_length" : 50
}

{
    "title": "Netflix", --> this should match both filetrs
    "url" : "www.netflix",
    "pgrk": 5,
    "url_length" : 50
}
```

{
    "title": "netflix",
    "url" : "www.netflix",
    "pgrk": 5,
    "url_length" : 80. --> note `pgrk` has same `5` as prev and url_length is diff
}

### Search query

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
        {
            "pgrk": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "url_length": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "netflix",
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "url"
                    ],
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            },
            "filter": [ --> note filter array to have multiple range queries in filter context
                {
                    "range": {
                        "pgrk": {
                            "gte": 1,
                            "lte" : 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "url_length": {
                            "lte": 100
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### And search result which brings only three docs (even 2 has same `pgrk` value)

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "so_range",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "netflix",
                    "url": "www.netflix.com",
                    "pgrk": 8,
                    "url_length": 50
                },
                "sort": [
                    8,
                    50
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "so_range",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "netflix",
                    "url": "www.netflix",
                    "pgrk": 5,
                    "url_length": 50
                },
                "sort": [
                    5,
                    50
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "so_range",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "netflix",
                    "url": "www.netflix",
                    "pgrk": 5,
                    "url_length": 80
                },
                "sort": [
                    5,
                    80
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Comment: If you create docs with the field (url_length) with different values, the query only works through the field filter (pgrk). The filter (url_length) does not work

Comment: @Jean, I tried with different value of `url_length` and it works fine for that, updating the answer

Comment: Hello @Opster

Let's say that in my mappings I have a name field (URL: "type": "keyword") that stores the urls of the indexed sites, there is some function in elasticsearch in which when indexing a DOC the elasticsearch itself counts the size of the Stored URL, without having to make this count of the URL size via PHP. Because I want to sort the results returned in the query by the size of the URL, from the smallest to the largest value. Thanks

Comment: @Jean, out of the box, elasticsearch doesn't provide such functionality, I am assuming size means MB here, you can do some hacks on elastic but that would be complex and as you are new to elastic wouldn't recommend that for you as it can lead to some unexpected results and poor performance which would be difficult for you to troubleshoot. you are already doing the right thing to calculate this size in you application and storing it in different field in Elastic :)

Comment: Hello @Opster I unselected the answer because I thought I couldn't ask any further questions if it was marked as done. I already scored again.

So the best way to know the size of the URL would be through a script like in PHP?

Comment: @Jean, welcome to SO, and you can comment always and for that you need not to again unselected the answer and it would be bad for the community as they won't be able to recognize whether the original question is answered or not, hope you understand this, and yeah IMO pre-comuting the size of URL in your PHP or application code seems best option.

Comment: @Jean anytime :)